# makeSceneTransitionAnimation in recyclerview Android

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, android-transitions, shared-element-transition

Edit in base of your answer: How I could i implement an interfercae to have the click listener in mmy activity

```
class ViewHolder(view: View,contex: Context) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view){
val chapterName = view.textrowlinear
val c=contex
var imageView=view.image_view
var motivo=view.motivomore
var cardView=view.card_viewl
```

Because i would like to implement the second and the best method u suggest
Thank You

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first parameter expected in `ActivityOptionsCompat.makeSceneTransitionAnimation` is Activity, here you are trying to pass a Context, which is a super class of Activity, so the compiler cannot identify if the context you passed is an activity or any other Context, the simplest solution would be to typecast the Context to an activity by using as keyword

```
  val intent = Intent(holder.c, Dialog::class.java)
//intent.putExtra("code", code)
val options = ActivityOptionsCompat.makeSceneTransitionAnimation(
    holder.c as Activity, holder.imageView, ViewCompat.getTransitionName(holder.imageView)!!)
holder.c.startActivity(intent, options.toBundle())
```

Or most correct implementation would be to use an interface to get back the event from Recyclerview adapter to activity and call these methods inside activity